# Launch notepad.exe from a PHP file

Tags: php, exec

In an attempt to simplify a problem I am having running a batch file from within PHP on a WAMP windows XP system I am trying to launch notepad.exe from a PHP file.  I have a PHP file containing....

```
<?php
exec('c:\windows\notepad.exe');
?>
```

When I run the PHP file I can see the notepad.exe process start in the task manager but notepad itself does not open.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your code and errors.

Comment: You cannot start an interactive program (e.g. notepad) from within a service. Such things would completely kill a server if that program then popped up a model dialog or something.

Comment: Would you mind describing the problem you are trying to "simplify"?

Comment: The problem I am trying to simplify is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125212/wamp-php-exec-command-not-working

Comment: I have now managed to get notepad.exe to launch,  I had to change a setting on the apache service within XP.  Still unable to make it launch a batch file though

Comment: Make sure the account running the apache service has access to the directory the batch file is in.

Comment: How would I do that?  Apache is set to launch under the XP Local System account.

Comment: You can change the account that the service runs under.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not the correct way, a notepad application is not a process to perform operations in background. But if you want to execute a command which will take time than by following way you can run external program in background. Means PHP will not wait for the external program termination.

```
$cmd = "somecommand";
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
} 
else { 
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want notepad to run interactively you can use [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

You can run a batch file from PHP with the exec command and psexec has the ability to run application interactively from within your batch file.

Comment: Form this resolve not working. I see run e.g notepad i task list, but I don't see notepad window in my system.